# 2nd order Differential equation(right side)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello I have the differntial equation (2nd order), I solved the homogenic part but the other (right side)not. Can anybody help me?
$$x''-2x'+3x=4e^t\cos(\sqrt{2}t)$$
$$x(\text{Homogenic})=e^t(c_1\cos(\sqrt{2}t) + c_2\sin(\sqrt{2}t))    $$
Now I need the other part but I don't know how to start. Thanks Ciwan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the differential equation is $$x''-2x'+3x=4e^t\cos(\sqrt{2}t)\implies(D^2-2D+3)x=4e^t\cos(\sqrt{2}t)$$ where $D\equiv \frac{d}{dt}$

> For the Particular Integral (i.e., P.I.) there are some general rules
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{D + a} \phi (x) = e^{-ax}\int e^{ax}\phi(x)$
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} e^{ax} \phi(x) = e^{ax}\frac{1}{f(D+a)} \phi(x)$
>
> $3.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \sin ax  = $Imaginary part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $4.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \cos ax  = $Real part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $5.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} (\cos ax + i\sin ax)  = \frac{1}{f(D)} x^n e^{iax}=e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$

To find the P.I. we use the **Rule$- 2$**

Here $f(D)=D^2-2D+3, \phi(t)=4\cos(\sqrt{2}t)$ and $a=1$

So P.I. $= \frac{1}{D^2-2D+3}4e^t\cos(\sqrt{2}t)$

$=4e^t\frac{1}{(D+1)^2-2(D+1)+3}\cos(\sqrt{2}t)$

$=4e^t\frac{1}{D^2+2}\cos(\sqrt{2}t)$

$=4e^t\sin(\sqrt{2}t)\frac{t}{2\sqrt 2}$

$=\sqrt 2 e^t\sin(\sqrt{2}t)$

---

For the Particular Integral (i.e., P.I.) of trigonometric functions  you have to follow the following rules:

> If $f(D)$ can be expressed as $\phi(D^2)$ and $\phi(-a^2)\neq 0$, then
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \sin ax=\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \sin ax = \frac{1}{\phi(-a^2)} \sin ax$
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \cos ax=\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \cos ax = \frac{1}{\phi(-a^2)} \cos ax$
>
> **Note:** If $f(D)$ can be expressed as $\phi(D^2)=D^2+a^2$, then $\phi(-a^2)= 0$.
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \sin ax =\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \sin ax=x\frac{1}{\phi'(D^2)} \sin ax= x \frac{1}{2D} \sin ax= -\frac{x}{2a} \cos ax$.
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \cos ax =\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \cos ax=x\frac{1}{\phi'(D^2)} \cos ax=  x \frac{1}{2D} \cos ax= \frac{x}{2a} \sin ax$.
>
> where $\phi'(D^2)\equiv\frac{d}{dD}\phi(D^2)$

Answer (score 0):

rewriting, $$(D^2 - 2D + 3)x = 4e^tcos(\sqrt2 t)$$ where $D = \frac{d}{dt}$. Then, $$x = \frac{1}{(D^2 - 2D + 3)}.4e^tcos(\sqrt2 t)$$
$$x = 4e^t\frac{1}{(D+1)^2 - 2(D+1) + 3}.cos(\sqrt2 t)$$
$$x = 4e^t\frac{1}{D^2 + 2}.cos(\sqrt2 t)$$
$$x = 4e^t\frac{t}{2\sqrt2}sin(\sqrt2t)$$ 
$$x = t\sqrt2e^tsin(\sqrt2t)$$
is the particular solution

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should find the complementary solution which is
$$x''-2x'+3x=0$$
$$r^2-2r+3=0$$
$$r=1\pm \sqrt{2}i$$
$$y_c=e^x(C_1\cos\sqrt{2}t+C_2\sin\sqrt{2}t)$$

The particular solution is
$$y_p=e^x(A\cos\sqrt{2}t+B\sin\sqrt{2}t)\rightarrow e^x(At\cos\sqrt{2}t+Bt\sin\sqrt{2}t)$$

then complete the solution to find the value of $A$ and $B$

Comment: How do you calculate the particular solution?